# Invoke-Command in function gives error message

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a function that will close the process on a remote computer using two parameters.

```
function close-process {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$comp,
    [String] $procname
    )  

$procItems = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {Get-Process -ComputerName $comp | Where-Object Name -Like "*$procname*"}

    if ($procItems) {
        Write-Host "Mentioned process has been found" -ForegroundColor DarkBlue
    }else {
        Write-Host "No process found with mentioned name"
        
    }

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {Get-Process -ComputerName $comp | Where-Object Name -Like "*$procname*" | Stop-Process}

}

close-process -comp COMPUTER01 -procname notepad
```

I got an error message:

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. 
Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingValida 
   tionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell. 
   Commands.GetProcessCommand
    + PSComputerName        : COMPUTER01
```

What could be the reason of this issue?

Comment: `Get-Process -ComputerName $comp |Where-Object ...` is redundant since `Get-Process` is already being executed _on the remote computer_. `Get-Process |Where-Object ...` will do

Comment: `$using:comp` inside invoke-command's scriptlbock